# Custom form in cart summary is added multiple times based on no of products added to cart

Tags: magento2, cart

I am facing a  strange issue where my custom form in phtml file is added multiple times as per no of products in cart.

Layout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.totals.container">
        <block class="Hosemart\ProdInquiry\Block\Inquiry" before="checkout.cart.totals" name="inquiry" template="inquiry.phtml" />
        <!-- <block class="Hosemart\ProdInquiry\Block\Totalqty" after="checkout.cart.form" name="totalqty" template="totalqty.phtml" /> -->
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

My phtml

```
  <?php if($block->isEnable()): ?>
<?php
$quote = $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();
$items = $quote->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {                                                                                                            
$toEmail = $block->getApiDefaultData("enquiry/general/email_address");
$product = $block->getCurrentProduct();
$productId = $item->getProductId();
$productName = $item->getName();
$productSku = $item->getSku();

$final_arr = $block->getCustomoptions($productId);
// echo "<pre>";
//  print_r($final_arr);die();


if (!empty($productId)) {
?>
<form class="form enquiry" action="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormAction()); ?>" 
      id="enquiry-form" method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Enquiry Us') ?></span></legend><br />
        <div class="hidden-fields">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($productId);?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($productName);?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="product_sku" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($productSku);?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="to_email" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($toEmail);?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="optiontitle" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($final_arr['optionTitle']);?>" />
             <input type="hidden" name="optionvalue" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($final_arr['optionValue']);?>" />

        </div>
        <div class="field first_name required">
            <label class="label" for="first_name"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Name') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="first_name" id="first_name" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Name') ?>" 
                    class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Email') ?>" class="input-text"
                    type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone required">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Phone Number') ?>"
                    class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field mobile">
            <label class="label" for="mobile"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Mobile Number') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="mobile" id="mobile" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Mobile Number') ?>"
                    class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field comment">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Comments') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Comments') ?>"
                    class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml('Submit Enquiry') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token">
</form>
<?php 
}
}
?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $sitekey = $this->getSitekey();?>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<?php echo $sitekey; ?>"></script>
<script>
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo $sitekey; ?>', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
        document.getElementById("token").value = token; 
        //console.log('reCAPTCHA token', token);
    });
});
</script>
```

If I add normal text then it is not an issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this corrected code for loop ,
Replace this with your forloop code and remove "}" after if condition 

`foreach($items as $item) {

$toEmail = $block->getApiDefaultData("enquiry/general/email_address");
$product = $block->getCurrentProduct();
$productId = $item->getProductId();
$productName = $item->getName();
$productSku = $item->getSku();
$final_arr = $block->getCustomoptions($productId);
// echo "";
//  print_r($final_arr);
}`